# How do the "Vorpal" and "Merciful" magic weapon special abilities interact on a crit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, critical-hit, nonlethal

Say someone manages to either find or create a +1 [*merciful*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/merciful/) [*vorpal*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/vorpal/) weapon and confirms a crit – what happens?

I personally see 2 possible outcomes:

1. *Merciful* takes effect and stops *vorpal* from functioning
2. *Vorpal* doesn’t do ‘damage’ and therefore functions as normal.

Does anyone know the proper interaction for these two magic weapon special abilities?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 2. Vorpal doesn’t do ‘damage’ and therefor functions as normal.

This one.

I don’t really know how to back this up; there isn’t really anything more to say other than the fact that *merciful* affects “damage” only, and the *vorpal* beheading effect isn’t “damage.” There’s just no interaction between the two.

“Damage” is a specific game term so suddenly shifting definitions away from the game terminology and into a general English-language understanding of the word, which would no doubt include beheading, isn’t supported by the rules and would be inconsistent even within the context of the *merciful* description (which refers to “1d6 nonlethal damage,” unquestionably using the word as the game term). And while it’s true that the rules **are** sometimes inconsistent like that, there’s just no evidence that they intend to do so here. Indeed, it is very unlikely that the authors ever consciously considered the combination at all, to even **have** any intention for how it would work.

Also, *merciful* converts “damage,” however we’re defining it, to nonlethal—which is to say, it doesn’t prevent the damage, it just prevents the damage from killing the target. Even if we really wanted to read “damage” as including the beheading, *merciful* still wouldn’t prevent the beheading—it would just somehow result in someone surviving without a head. Since the game has no rules for how **that** would work (nor do we have any applicable real-world intuition for most targets), we’re well into undefined behavior here—a strong sign that we were never meant to go this way.

It would be reasonable for a GM to prevent the creation of such a weapon, or to block the *vorpal* effect while the *merciful* effect is activated, or to houserule some special effect for the interaction (guaranteed KO, maybe?), but the rules don’t support any of that.

Comment: Personally, since Vorpal is a stronger enhancement at +5 while Merciful is +1, when the conditions are correct, vorpal takes effect

Comment: @Fering reasonable, but not supported by the rules.

Comment: As a GM, I would make Vorpal give you a cursed neckache you can only heal with a blessed pillow ;-).

Comment: Ever heard of the comics Dungeon? The hero have the Sword of Destiny that can behead without killing.

Comment: I agree that RAW both effects would function as normal, ergo it produces a weapon whose damage rolls are non lethal with the exception of the nat20 also triggering vorpal's beheading where applicable.
But personally, the idea of combining both merciful and vorpal makes me think of a kind of cursed weapon, that can only kill on a nat20 but otherwise won't harm the enemies. :)

Comment: As a compromise, you could make the effect work as [Decollate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/decollate/).